# Выводит две записи запрос в Laravel

Tags: laravel

есть таблица dialogs

```
id | recipient_id | user_id
```

и запрос

```
$dialogs = DB::table('dialogs')
                ->join('users', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('users.id', '=', 'dialogs.recipient_id')->orOn('users.id', '=', 'dialogs.user_id');
                })
                ->leftJoin('user_attributes','user_attributes.user_id','=','users.id')
                ->select('user_attributes.fullname','user_attributes.avatar','user_attributes.age','users.email','dialogs.id')
                ->where('dialogs.user_id','=', Auth::user()->id)
                ->orWhere('dialogs.recipient_id','=', Auth::user()->id)->distinct('dialogs.id')
                ->get();
```

мне нужно вывести пользователей, с кем у меня диалог, либо я user_id  либо я recipient_id

этот запрос, что у меня выводит в моих диалогах и меня и пользователя с кем я переписывался

Answer (score 0):

решил так

```
$dialogs = DB::table('dialogs')
                ->leftJoin('users', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('users.id', '=', 'dialogs.recipient_id')
                        ->where('dialogs.user_id','=', Auth::user()->id)
                        ->orOn('users.id', '=', 'dialogs.user_id')
                        ->where('dialogs.recipient_id','=', Auth::user()->id);
                })
                ->leftJoin('user_attributes','user_attributes.user_id','=','users.id')
                ->select('user_attributes.fullname','user_attributes.avatar','user_attributes.age','users.email','dialogs.id')
                ->where('dialogs.user_id','=', Auth::user()->id)
                ->orWhere('dialogs.recipient_id','=', Auth::user()->id)->distinct('dialogs.id')
                ->get();
```